# Error trying to connect to oracle express 10 with C# using OracleConnection

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

Im developing an application in .Net(3.5) C# and Oracle Express 10g. When I try to connecto to database I got this error:

From OracleConnection Object I got, in ServerVersion property:

`ServerVersion = 'conn.ServerVersion' produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

and, in the catch:

`ORA-12154:  TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Im working with this connectionstring:

`Data Source=Angelo-HP/XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456;`

my tnsnames.ora is set:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Angelo-HP)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
  )
)

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = PLSExtProc)
    (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
)

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
  ) 
  (CONNECT_DATA = 
    (SID = CLRExtProc) 
    (PRESENTATION = RO) 
  ) 
)
```

and my sqlnet.ora like this:

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)`

any idea Why I cant connect?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with setting the datasource as XE in your connectionstring. And could you translate the errormessages in English? Easier to understand for us ;-)

Comment: 'conn.ServerVersion' an exception ocurred of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Can you `tnsping` the identifier?

Comment: what do you mean by tnsing? and Im using System.Data.OracleClient;

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string  is mentioned as

```
Data Source=Angelo-HP/XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456;
```

Which means it's looking for a TNSNAME of Angelo-HP/XE, which isn't present in the TNS names and hence you're getting the error message

Change it to

```
Data Source=XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456;
```

Comment: open command prompt, type in `tnsping XE`. What does it say? @Angelo

Comment: I have changed my sqlnet.ora to this:

automatic_ipc = OFF               # Set to OFF for PC's
trace_level_client = OFF         # Set to 16 if tracing is required
sqlnet.expire_time = 0           # Idle time in minutes
sqlnet.authentication_services = (ALL)
names.directory_lookup = (TNSNAMES,ONAMES,HOSTNAME)

and now I got Success for XE

Comment: but still cant connect from .Net

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Datasource-property to XE as mentioned in my comment.

```
Data Source=XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456;
```

Also you got to be sure there's no space in front of the identifier in your tnsnames.

Another thing: if you have multiple oracle-clients installed, you have to make sure that this entry is in the correct tnsnames.

Comment: I did, now my connection String is:

    Data Source=XE;User ID=MAPFRE;Password=123456;

I only have one oracle client that is oracle express 10g. Its the first time i install oracle.